# Laravel sort table alphabetically

Tags: mongodb, laravel, sorting, laravel-5, database

I have a HTML table and there is some data from the database (MongoDB) of my website (Laravel 5.1). There are different dog names which comes from my site

Now it looks like this:

```
row1: Bello
row2: Rex
row3: Ace
row4: Elvis
row6: Benny
row7: Sam
row8: Rusty
```

The number of dogs and the names could be different. But they should all the time sorted alphabetically. How can I do this?

Comment: In your controller how do you return the list of dogs ?

Comment: Like this:  {{ array_get($oParticipant->dog,'name') }}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to sort directly from MongoDb using the `cursor.sort()` here is the documentation [cursor.sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#cursor.sort)

Answer (score 0):

Change your array into a Laravel Collection before you send it to the view.  Laravel Collections act similar to an Array, but Laravel offers a variety of very useful methods you can call against a collection.  [Laravel Collections Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections)

If your result set isn't already in a laravel collection object, then I'd change it to one.

In this example I'll assume your mongo Database array is named $yourCurrentArray and that your dog name field is named 'dog_name'.

Hope This helps.

```
//This will change your array into a collection.
$dogCollection = collect($yourCurrentArray);

//This will use the sortBy method available with Laravel Collections.
$dogCollectionSorted = $dogCollection->sortBy('dog_name');
```